# sql how to add value by condition and put in specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the table and data in the table.

**Table:**

```
id |value_total|value_1|value_2|value_3|value_4 
1  | 100       | 50    | 0     | 0     | 50
2  | 200       | 0     | 150   | 50    | 0
3  | 300       | 100   | 200   | 0     | 0
4  | 400       | 100   | 200   | 0     | 100
```

I need table having the below data.

**desire result:**

```
id |value_total|value_1|value_2|value_3|value_4 
1  | 100       | 0     | 0     | 0     | 100
2  | 200       | 0     | 0     | 200   | 0
3  | 300       | 0     | 300   | 0     | 0
4  | 400       | 0     | 0     | 0     | 400
```

Comment: How do you know what column the value should go in?

Comment: can you explain it.

Comment: the value will go to column that not 0 and the last one...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to put the total value in the last non-zero column?

```
select id, value_total,
       (case when value_2 = 0 and value_3 = 0 and value_4 = 0 and value_1 > 0
             then value_total else 0
        end) as value_1,
       (case when value_3 = 0 and value_4 = 0 and value_2 > 0
             then value_total else 0
        end) as value_2,
       (case when value_4 = 0 and value_3 > 0
             then value_total else 0
        end) as value_3,
       (case when value_4 > 0 then value_total else 0 end)
from t;
```

Comment: yes but how if my value_ is  dynamic ? for example it depend on input... in can be value_1, value_2 only sometime until value_8

Comment: I think you changed your question again. You never mentioned the columns are dynamic or there 8 different value columns. However, you can re-write the above-posted code up to the column value_8, if that's the case.

Comment: @azizi . . . Then you would have a different question.  This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for this scenario ,one of them is mentioned below please have a look.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET value_1 = 0
    ,value_2 = CASE 
        WHEN id = 3
            THEN 300
        ELSE 0
        END
    ,value_3 = CASE 
        WHEN id = 2
            THEN 200
        ELSE 0
        END
    ,value_4 = CASE 
        WHEN id = 1
            THEN 100
        WHEN id = 4
            THEN 400
        ELSE 0
        END
```